# [ros2] sensor message publisher does not abandon old data

Tags: navigation, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am streaming small pointclouds over wifi for navigation2 using opensplice as my dds impl.

Sometimes, I get messages like these for minutes at a time:

```
[world_model-4] [INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap_rclcpp_node]: [signalFailure] Drop message: frame 'camera_depth_optical_frame' at time 1566597372.636 for reason(1)
```

I looked into what reason(1) is and saw that it is 'OutTheBack'.

I then started echoing the pointcloud data and my tf data to my terminal.

When my system is working well, both topics are publishing data at >10Hz with real-time time stamps .

However, sometimes my system enters a state where the pointcloud data is still publishing fast (>10Hz) but it starts to lag behind real-time, until it gets so bad that my most recent pointcloud data is 10 seconds stale compared to my most recent transform data.

I believe this is what's causing my  'OutTheBack' error.

What can I do to fix this? Currently, my publisher and subscriber are set to 'sensor' quality of service, with a depth of 10.

I recently moved from fastRTPS as my dds impl, where I had never hit this 'OutTheBack' error. This is why I don't believe there is a logic error in the time stamp construction of the message.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331490/%5Bros2%5D-sensor-message-publisher-does-not-abandon-old-data/) by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2019-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Either my publisher or subscriber was incorrectly configured for reliable quality of service, while the other was configured for best effort. When I fixed the system and set both to best effort, my performance improved a lot.

So the answer to this was "programmer error". Whoops!

---

Originally posted by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) with karma: 553 on 2019-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ninamwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/45886/ninamwa/) on 2019-12-03**:
Hi. I am having the exact same problem as you did. How did you change the code to best effort?
My publishers and subscribers also have a qos with depth of 10.

**Comment by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on 2019-12-03**:
I usually use the sensor message QoS( `rclcpp::SensorDataQoS()` ) when I'm looking for best effort.this [design doc](https://design.ros2.org/articles/qos.html) talks about  QoS and mentions sensor QoS tradeoffs.